# How to get ASP.NET MVC IAuthorizationFilter to respect IgnoreRoute's

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ignoreroute, iauthorizationfilter

I am using the popular [Elmah.MVC](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/elmah-mvc) error logging NuGet package. So I can navigate to /elmah to view my error logs. I have the following IgnoreRoute statements, so that MVC ignores the /elmah route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah");
routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah/{*pathinfo}");
```

I have written the following authorization filter. How can I stop the filter below from executing when I navigate to /elmah. Surely there must be some way for it to respect the routes I tell it to ignore?

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // I don't want /elmah routes to execute this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have this ignore rout?
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Because you access elmah.axd url.

Comment: I have that but I have configured Elmah to be accessed from /elmah, rather than /elmah.axd

Comment: Also try putting this line after (Ignore Route): routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

Comment: IgnoreRoutes was never intended for security; it was only intended for routing rules.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to check the ControllerName that was executing and if it is Elmah, we return and ignore this request.

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // I don't want /elmah routes to execute for this filter.
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        if (string.Equals(controllerName, "Elmah", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```